# How to define global variable for Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm using a file serving as a form layout to overwrite certain elements (*form_start*, *form_row*, etc.). I register it like:

```
twig:
    - AcmeMainBundle:Form:formlayout.html.twig
```

Is there a way to use in it my variables provided along with a **form**?

For example, when I send to **index.html.twig**

```
array ('form' => $formView, 'var' => $var);
```

Var is defined only in **index.html.twig**.

So how to make **var** defined in **formlayout.html.twig**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `addGlobal()` method.

For example in BaseController I use:

```
$this->get('twig')->addGlobal('is_test', $isTest);
```

so in your case you should probably do:

```
$this->get('twig')->addGlobal('var', $var);
```

Comment: Do you add it in the constructor of your BaseController or in an other way?

Comment: how do u override the global variable?

Comment: @slier (and anyone else that wonders how to override them) according to the [code](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/2.x/src/Environment.php#L904)  `addGlobal` is just an array assignment, so it will also override

Answer (score 11):

In case you don't use symphony but use twig on it's own, it is as simple as:

```
<?php

$loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem('path/to/templates');
$twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addGlobal('key1', 'var1');
$twig->addGlobal('key2', 'var2');
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I don't use Symfony and was looking for a while for this info.

Answer (score 5):

To set a global variable in Twig I created a service call "@get_available_languages" (return an array) and then on my kernel.request event class I implemented the below:

```
  class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale = 'en',       ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        //Add twig global variables
        $this->addTwigGlobals();


    }



    public function addTwigGlobals(){

        //Add avaialble language to twig template as a global variable
        $this->container->get('twig')->addGlobal('available_languages', $this->container->get('get_available_languages'));

    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered before the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 17)),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not inject the whole container here, just the requested services.

Answer (score -1):

Better Example:

You can transfer  all $_GET, $_POST and $_SESSION so:

```
$twig->addGlobal('session', $_SESSION);
$twig->addGlobal('get', $_GET);
$twig->addGlobal('post', $_POST);
```

Comment: Please share more details. Why should this be needed anywhere? Accessing these variables directly in your template is a good sign that your templates are tied too close to these variables, instead of working with abstractions like a request object