# How can i create the global variable in symfony controller

Tags: symfony

How can  i create the global variable in symfony controller like in laravel (example: view()->share('now', date('Y-m-d')); ), that it availiable in all templates?

Comment: [Symfony Documentation: How to Inject Variables into all Templates](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html)

Comment: @ccKep Well answered. Here you have a lot of info related with globals in templates in Docs. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Setting a global template variable

[It is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812170/how-to-define-global-variable-for-twig) to set a global variable available in every template using the `addGlobal` function in the `BaseController` class.

```
$this->get('twig')->addGlobal('today', date('Y-m-d'));
```

---

### The Twig `date` functions

Remember that Twig is at its core simply a templating enging for php; it's a skin, an illusion. It replaces the old style `<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>` commonly used in php. This means two things:

1. Twig statements are executed server-side
2. Twig can access (most) php's native function

So in order to set a global variable with today's date, you can imply add the following line:

```
{% set today = date() %}
```

If you want to have `today` be available every template, simply set it in your `base.twig.html` template. Alternatively you can also use the function only when needed.

Comment: I think that the solution of set it in your base.twig.html is the best. If you only need the date you dont need use the controller to do that. im right?

Comment: @Oscar Pretty much, imho using the controller to set a global variable is going the long way around a simple solution

Answer (score 0):

Set it as a class property. Eg

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    private $now = new \DateTime();

    public function page1Action()
    {
        $this->render('...', ['now'=>$this->now]);
    }

    public function page2Action()
    {
        $this->render('...', ['now'=>$this->now]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one possibility is to create variable in session like this.

```
$session = $this->get('session');
$session->set('var', $my_variable);
```

in another controller you just get it like this

```
$session->get('var');
```

in twig you can get your variable

```
{% app.session.get('var') %}
```

it can resolve your issue and it is avalaible for a user not globally.