# Twig, insert php defined variables without passing it explicitly

Tags: php, twig

My PHP page looks like

```
<?php
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once '../utils/index.php';

$loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader('../templates');
$twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader);

$template = $twig->load('routes/features/page_x.html');
echo $twig->render('routes/features/page_x.html', [
  'title' => 'A Remote Access and Monitoring system',
]);

?>
```

In `utils/index.php` I defined a PHP variable, e.g. `$utm_campaign = 'navbar';`

There is the possibility to access to that variable, e.g. `$utm_campaign`, without passing it explicitly into the Twig->render array?

Comment: You can add it as a [global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812170/how-to-define-global-variable-for-twig) twig variable before you call the `render()` method.

Comment: Just note that if you add it as a global, it will be accessible from all templates.